# What happened to the first Hari put in a escape capsule by Kris in Solaris?

Tags: solaris

I've read the new direct translation to English of Lem's *Solaris*.

In the book Snaut is trying to reason with Kris about the futility of his relationship and threatens recalling the #1 Hari that Kris sent in a capsule into orbit so that there would be two Hari's on the station. Kris protests. Later in the book #2 Hari is annihilated and the book ends with Kris remaining on the station without hope of either contacting the sea or seeing Hari again.

Therefore it's implied by Snaut that Hari #1 is still 'alive' orbiting Solaris. Why did Kris not recall the capsule and reunite with her? It is also suggested that the field that stabilises the 'visitor's' neutrinos have a limited range, but orbit was suggested to be only 600km, using an inverse square law the field strength would be very similar to what is on the station (think about the gravity on the ISS it is practically the same as that terrestrial).

Comment: I always assumed she starved to death.

Comment: they regenerate so death seems only possible through annihilation not starvation.